# Reading UTF-8 text and converting to UTF-16 using standard C++ wifstream

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8, visual-studio-2013, iostream

I'd like to read some text from a file that uses UTF-8 encoding and convert it to UTF-16, using `std::wifstream`, something like this:

```
//
// Read UTF-8 text and convert to UTF-16
//
std::wifstream src;
src.imbue(std::locale("???"));          // UTF-8 ???
src.open("some_text_file_using_utf8");
std::wstring line;                      // UTF-16 string
while (std::getline(src, line))
{
    ... do something processing the UTF-16 string ...
}
```

Is there a standard locale name for the UTF-8 conversion?
Is it possible to achieve that goal using `std::locale`?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

---

**NOTE:**

I know that I/O streams tend to be slow, and it's possible to use Win32 memory mapped files for faster reading, and `MultiByteToWideChar()` Win32 API for the conversion, etc.
But for this particular case I'd like a solution that only uses **standard C++ and its standard library**, *without* Boost.

If the C++ standard library just can't do that, the *second* option would be to use *Boost*; in this case, which Boost library should I use?

Comment: I *think* you want to use the codecvt facet from the localization library, if I understand your question correctly. [See the related documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt), and particularly the sample code. [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) would be a likely candidate.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks for the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt): the sample code provided there seems to work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works on Windows with Visual Studio, I think as far back as VS2010

```
#include <locale>  // consume_header, locale
#include <codecvt> // codecvt_utf8_utf16

src.imbue(std::locale(
    src.getloc(),
    new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10FFFF, std::consume_header>));
```

Since Windows uses a 16-bit `wchar_t` and also universally uses UTF-16 as the wide character encoding this works great in that environment. (And because I'm assuming a Windows environment my example includes [`consume_header`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode) to handle Windows' convention of adding a header to UTF-8 data).

On other platforms `wchar_t` is generally 32-bit and, while you can store UTF-16 code unit values in such 32-bit code units, nothing else will be written expecting such a thing. On a platform with 32-bit `wchar_t` you might prefer to use `std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>` to produce UTF-32 wide strings.

---

For portability ideally what you'd want is a codecvt facet that knows how to convert from UTF-8 to either the locale's `wchar_t` encoding or the wide execution encoding. The problem with that, however, is that there's no requirement for any wide encoding to support the entire range of characters representable in UTF-8. The bottom line is that `wchar_t` isn't particularly useful for portable code as specified.

However one trick that might be useful if you're sticking to platforms that use UTF-16 or UTF-32 depending on the size of `wchar_t` is:

```
template <int N> struct get_codecvt_utf8_wchar_impl;
template <> struct get_codecvt_utf8_wchar_impl<16> {
  using type = std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>;
};
template <> struct get_codecvt_utf8_wchar_impl<32> {
  using type = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
};

using codecvt_utf8_wchar = get_codecvt_utf8_wchar_impl<
    sizeof(wchar_t) * CHAR_BIT>::type;

src.imbue(std::locale(src.getloc(), new codecvt_utf8_wchar));
```

---

You can also use `char16_t` and `char32_t`, which would lend themselves to portable code, however the standard is missing a few bits to make iostreams usable with these character types and also implementations don't fully support what is specified.

VS I think still implements `char16_t` and `char32_t` as typedefs and so the template specializations using them don't work (even though the specializations *do* exist if you look in the headers, they're just ifdef'd out because the compiler can't handle them). libstdc++ doesn't implement the template specializations yet even though it supports `char16_t` and `char32_t` as real types. The most complete implementation I know of is libc++ with a suitable compiler (gcc or clang), but even that is still missing the `<cuchar>` header.

Since implementation support is limited that sort of prevents portable code from doing much with these besides using them as a consistent representation in user code across platforms (though that is useful even on its own).

Comment: Before reading your answer, I tried this: `src.imbue(locale(src.getloc(), new codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>()));` basing on the link provided by @WhozCraig as a comment to my question. It seems to work fine for me with this simplified form. Are the two additional template arguments you specify to `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<>` after `wchar_t` necessary, and if so, why?

Comment: @Mr.C64 The added argument that matters is `consume_header`, which is there because UTF-8 files in a Windows environment often include some extra bytes at the beginning that are not really part of the content. `consume_header` will skip that header so that your program only handles the real content of the file. On other platforms the simpler version is fine so long as one doesn't expect to handle Windows UTF-8 data.

Comment: Thanks! I've just found and read [that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode). You may want to add a small note on that in your answer to make it excellent.