# Microsoft C++ implementation of std::mbstate_t

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some legacy code that works with UTF8/16 conversions and wstream-s. It has been written on VS08-VS10 and it assumes that `mbstate_t`'s type is `int`. It uses it to check on some states like

```
while(_State & 0x80000000 && ...)
```

and

```
unsigned n = _State & 0x7FFFFFFF; 
if(n<=0x3F)...
```

But now I need to compile it with modern Visual studio, and there mbstate is presented as a struct:

```
typedef struct _Mbstatet
{ // state of a multibyte translation
    unsigned long _Wchar;
    unsigned short _Byte, _State;
} _Mbstatet;
```

I can guess that in need to use `_State` field in all provided above operations. But it is just 16 bit whereas in my legacy it's used with 32bit constants. I am trying to find some documentation about it, but I've not got success yet. Have someone experienced with that?

Comment: This is undocumented for a reason - you are not supposed to write code that depends on the implementation at all. The code needs to be rewritten. (Also, identifiers beginning with underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstate_t

Comment: If you quoted more of your code someone might be able to take an educated guess at what the code is trying to do, and even show the correct way to write the code.

Comment: Well, I figured that It is a Facet used to read/write UTF-8 bytes into UTF-16 streams. So I think I can just replace all the code with some Boost implementation

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out that it's a bad idea to have assumptions on internal implementations. 
So, I used 
`#if _MSC_VER >= 1925`
for my code + an answer from here: [Reading UTF-8 text and converting to UTF-16 using standard C++ wifstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636374/reading-utf-8-text-and-converting-to-utf-16-using-standard-c-wifstream)